# How to make Bitbucket API calls with access token?

Tags: c#, oauth, bitbucket, restsharp, bitbucket-api

I created an ASP.NET MVC application which can authorize the user at Bitbucket.
I used [CSharp.Bitbucket library](https://github.com/scottksmith95/CSharp.Bitbucket) to get the token secret and token value.

The [OAuth tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/OAuth+on+Bitbucket) said that with the token I can make API calls.

I know that I can call the API using basic authorization like this way:

```
 string url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/";
 var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

 string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password"));
 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

 using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
 {
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

But how can I call the API using the access token?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

1. First you create an "Oauth Consumer" in APPS AND FEATURES section of your bitbucket account setting. This gives you a "Key" and a "Secret".
2. Now using these Key and Secret you ask Bitbucket for a token. In my case I made a http request to `https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token`. In your case you should use a .net equivalent. I could do it with Curl or some Ajax library like this:

   ```
   curl -X POST -u "yourKeyHere:yourSecretHere"  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d  grant_type=client_credentials
   ```

alternatively, my http request was like this (using superagent in node) with my `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
    request.post("https://yourKeyHere:yourSecretHere@bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/      access_token").send('grant_type=client_credentials');`
```

the result is like this:

```
    {
       "access_token": "blah blah blah HXAhrfr8YeIqGTpkyFio=",
       "scopes": "pipeline snippet issue pullrequest project team account",
       "expires_in": 3600,
       "refresh_token": "hsadgsadvkQ",
       "token_type": "bearer"
    }
```

3. Now that you have the token, send it in a request header:
   `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}`

More info here [bitbucket's api doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication)